# How to write MySQL query on 2 different tables residing in 2 different databases on 2 different servers?

Tags: mysql, multiple-databases

I have 2 tables

> **table1** in database1 on server1 having
>   **userID and userName**
>
> **table2** in database2 on server2 having
>   **userID**

I need a way to access table1 on server1 to get the userName of the userID in table2

How do I do query using MySQL?

Comment: If you indicate the language that you are using, you'd probably get an answer that contained working code. Consider updating?

Comment: MySQL and C# is what im using it can be php too

Comment: Use federated engine. Refer: http://winashwin.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/mysql-federated-table/

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use 2 different connections:

```
$connection1= mysql_connect('server1', 'user1', 'password1');
$connection2= mysql_connect('server2', 'user2', 'password2');
```

Retrieve data from database 1, and use it to query database2. Or the opposite, depending on what you need. This means you'll use 2 queries.

Edit: I automatically assumed you're using php, hence my answer. I'm sorry if it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports [federated tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) - tables housed in a physically distinct server instance. It makes the remote table appear local, and any queries executed on it are transparently sent to the remote server for execution.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about mysql...

in Oracle you would link the databases and then fully qualify the table references in your query (with '.' seperators)